# Same APN certificate for AppID with namespace extensions

Tags: apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I am currently working with an application which uses APNS.

However, we have the convention of creating different namespace extensions for different versions of the same application. For example,

```
AppID 1: com.example.abc.dev
AppID 2: com.example.abc.sit
AppID 3: com.example.abc.uat
```

Would it be possible to use just one APN cert or provisionning profile across all three AppIDs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, instead of creating 3 AppIds, create one with asterisk.

Instead this,

```
AppID 1: com.example.abc.dev
AppID 2: com.example.abc.sit
AppID 3: com.example.abc.uat
```

create this, `AppID 1: com.example.abc.*`, add your devices & update your XCode Bundle id.

Comment: yeah i thought of that. but i have yet to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, you can't use push notifications with wildcard app id's.

Comment: hm. i was aware of the explicit appID policy. however, i was wondering if the rules could be bent a little to put it partially like  **com.example.abc.***

Comment: i mean put a wildcard after our "official" identifier followed by different stages of release.